# Need to make a function that uses &rest and sums the rest of parameters together

Tags: functions

I am learning ELISP and this function should gather any number of parameters plus N and return the sum. This what I've got so far and I cannot figure out where my error is. Also if a char is in the list it should just skip over and not add that to the value.

```lisp
    (defun sum-numbers (n &rest L)
      (let (a 0)
        (if (not L) n
          (dolist (x L result)
        (if (integerp x)
            (setq a (+ x a)))))
        (setq a (+ a n))))
```

Comment: You already [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66897414/850781). I think you should remove one of the two questions.

Comment: Yes, please choose one and remove the other. Thx.

Comment: The question is unclear. Say what you expect the function to do. Say what the function actually does. `dolist` evaluates its 3rd arg and then returns the result of evaluation, but `result` is an undefined variable, so evaluation raises an error. And you probably are missing parens around your `(a 0)` `let` binding. This looks a bit like a homework assignment, BTW.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been asked *and answered* on Stack Overflow, and it currently has no answers here.  (Edit: Ugh... since I loaded the tab it's been answered here as well, so now there are cross-site duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun sum-numbers (n &rest L)
      (let ((a 0))
        (if (not L) n
          (dolist (x L a)
        (if (integerp x)
            (setq a (+ x a))))
        (setq a (+ a n)))))
```

an other solution using a sequence function:

```
(defun sum-numbers (n &rest L)
  (apply #'+ (cons n (seq-filter #'integerp L))))
```